# an idiom about moving to somewhere

Tags: idiomatic-language, politeness, idiom-request

I want to ask someone **why on earth he moved from A (a city with high standards of living) to B (a disastrous one)**, because it's unreasonable and I'm nosy, through a *polite* idiom. Is there anything for this purpose??

Comment: You can say "I am interested in why you **relocated** from A to B." That is not even a question, but an invitation to talk. For him, with his own reasons and values, it might not have been at all disastrous – or it might have been an unwelcome move he was somehow forced to make. If you want to be polite, you won't impose your own value judgements on his decision, and if you do, he might be unwilling to tell you.

Comment: @WeatherVane thank you ...really useful pieces of advice. I thought perhaps there are any sorts of idiomatic language to approach that Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An idiom you can use is '**up sticks**'. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/up_sticks) says

> **up sticks**
> PHRASE
> *informal British*
>
> Go to live elsewhere.
> *I'm unlikely to up sticks and go to a developing country.*

---

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/up%20sticks) has

> **up sticks** idiom
> *British, informal*
>
> : to pack up one's belongings and move to a different place
> // They *upped sticks* and left for London.

---

So you can ask them

> Why did you **up sticks** and move to B?

This means a lot more than 'move' or 'depart for'. The idea expressed is that you pulled up your roots and made a complete relocation.

Comment: thanks mate :) ...this idiom is new to me